# Mysql join on json value issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

i have the folowwing tables on mysql 5.7 server

`produit__parure`

| id_parure (int) | ids_produits_parure (json) |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | ["34809", "34823", "34813"] |
| 22 | ["35703", "35854", "35877"] |

and `produit` :

| id_product (int) | ... other columns |
| --- | --- |
| 34809 | ... |
| 34810 | ... |

i try to join both on id.prod = value on ids_produits_parure with this query:

```
SELECT p.id_prod, pp.* FROM produit p left JOIN produit__parure pp on
JSON_CONTAINS(pp.ids_produits_parure->'$[*]', CAST(p.id_prod as JSON))
where id_prod=34809
```

but it return NULL on produit__parure fileds:

| id_prod | id_parure | ids_produits_parure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34809 | NULL | NULL |

what am i doing wrong?
what i want as a result is:

| id_prod | id_parure | ids_produits_parure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34809 | 21 | ["34809", "34823", "34813"] |

i tried Dan Chase answer but it produce wrong results (i have lines with ids_produits_parure not equal to id_prod )

| id_prod | id_parure | ids_produits_parure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34809 | 21 | ["34809", "34823", "34813"] |
| 34809 | 22 | ["35703", "35854", "35877"] |

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are only selecting the ID as JSON on JSON_CONTAINS? I don't know what the resulting code should look like, except maybe something similar:

```
JSON_CONTAINS(pp.ids_produits_parure->'$[*]', CAST(pp as JSON))
```

because I doubt the ID is an array, and wouldn't you search pp not p?

Reference:
[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#:~:text=JSON_CONTAINS%20%28target%2C%20candidate%20%5B%2C%20path%20%5D%29%20Indicates%20by,found%20at%20a%20specific%20path%20within%20the%20target.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#:%7E:text=JSON_CONTAINS%20%28target%2C%20candidate%20%5B%2C%20path%20%5D%29%20Indicates%20by,found%20at%20a%20specific%20path%20within%20the%20target.)

Comment: i tried Dan Chase answer but it produce wrong results (i have line with ids_produits_parure not equal to id_prod )
id_prod  id_parure  ids_produits_parure
34809  21  ["34809", "34823", "34813"]
34809  22  ["35703", "35854", "35877"]

Comment: I think we need more definition on what the data set is, and what you are trying to accomplish, so that we can suggest an appropriate query structure. Your intent changes everything above. My answer only outlines the reason it has NULLs, which is what you asked, but I can't predict what it should return. Your added comments add clarity as we go, but we need it up front.

Answer (score 0):

Your KSON_CONTAINS is a bit of.

Json are in most cases tricky to handle, so you should condsider switching to a normalized design

> ```
> CREATE TABLE produit__parure
>     (`id_parure` int, `ids_produits_parure` json)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO produit__parure
>     (`id_parure`, `ids_produits_parure`)
> VALUES
>     ('21', '["34809", "34823", "34813"]'),
>     ('22', '["35703", "35854", "35877"]')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE produit
>     (`id_product` int, `other columns` varchar(3))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO produit
>     (`id_product`, `other columns`)
> VALUES
>     (34809, '...'),
>     (34810, '...')
> ```
>
> ;

> ```
> SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(`ids_produits_parure`, CONCAT('"','34809' ,'"'), '$') FROM produit__parure
> ```
>
> ```
> | JSON_CONTAINS(`ids_produits_parure`, CONCAT('"','34809' ,'"'), '$') |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------: |
> |                                                                   1 |
> |                                                                   0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT p.id_product, pp.* FROM produit p left JOIN produit__parure pp on
> JSON_CONTAINS(pp.ids_produits_parure, CONCAT('"',p.id_product,'"'),'$')
> where id_product=34809
> ```

> ```
> id_product | id_parure | ids_produits_parure                                   
> ---------: | --------: | :-----------------------------------------------------
>      34809 |        21 | 5b223334383039222c20223334383233222c20223334383133225d
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=02db771a551b6b52e207e59f216f4d18)*

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the result is strange, why do we have : 
5b223334383039222c20223334383233222c20223334383133225d instead of the correct ids_products_parure values?

Comment: it work well on my server i have the correct result, thank you again